# Can someone help me fix the matching numbers of repeating numbers?

Tags: php

I have a script that creates two sets of numbers:
1. a list of random numbers
2. a list of match numbers of repeating numbers

But the list of match numbers of repeating numbers is not working properly.

Let me give an example:
Random numbers
5-14-5-4-15-12-8-10-18-13-11-25-15-14-2-7-24-22-13-22-16-18-10-11-25-2-18-9-19-8-1-16-1-23-0-16-17-23-21-20-22-21-9-4-20-24-19-16-9-17

Match numbers
3-11-2-6-2-3-2-2-2-2-2-4-3-2-4-3-4-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2

If you look at the random numbers you see the first match number is the correct. After three numbers we have a match so that match number is 3. Then we start counting from the 5 and the next match number is also correct which is 11 and ends at number 15. But then we should have a match after 2 numbers but this does not work out properly.

Can someone assist me here?

```
<?php
$existing = [];
$repeat_numbers = [];

for ($rnd=1;$rnd<=50;$rnd++)
{
$randoms[] = mt_rand(0,25);
}
echo implode('-',$randoms).PHP_EOL;

echo "<br><br>";

$i = 1;
 foreach($randoms as $rnd){
 if(in_array($rnd,$existing)){
     $repeat_numbers[] = $i;
     $i=1;
 }
 $existing[] = $rnd;
 $i++;
 }
echo implode('-',$repeat_numbers);
?>
```

Comment: And what is expected result ?

Comment: The match numbers shoould be:
3-11-8-8-7-6-8

Comment: Why? And what about 14, which  at the 2nd position and after the 2nd 15 ?

Comment: I only want to have the match numbers when a number repeats. So when a number repeats we have a match number and after this happened the counting should start all over until we have another repeat which creates the next repeat number.

Comment: Clear  $existing when  match found ?

Comment: No, I want to have all matches beside eachother.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per your expected match, **"The match numbers should be: 3-11-8-8-7-6-8"**

```
<?php
$existing = [];
$repeat_numbers = [];
$randoms = explode('-','5-14-5-4-15-12-8-10-18-13-11-25-15-14-2-7-24-22-13-22-16-18-10-11-25-2-18-9-19-8-1-16-1-23-0-16-17-23-21-20-22-21-9-4-20-24-19-16-9-17');
//print_r($randoms);
$i = 0;
foreach($randoms as $rnd){
   $i++; 
   if(in_array($rnd,$existing)){
       $repeat_numbers[] = $i;
       $i=1;
       $existing = [];
   }
   $existing[] = $rnd; 
}
echo implode('-',$repeat_numbers);
?>
```

**WORKING DEMO:** https://3v4l.org/HbFnV

Then just add this instead of hard coded `$random` string variable and use the rest of the code as usual.

```
<?php
$existing = [];
$repeat_numbers = [];
for ($rnd=1;$rnd<=50;$rnd++)
{
  $randoms[] = mt_rand(0,25);  // see this block for generating randoms
}
$i = 0;
foreach($randoms as $rnd){
   $i++; 
   if(in_array($rnd,$existing)){
       $repeat_numbers[] = $i;
       $i=1;
       $existing = [];
   }
   $existing[] = $rnd; 
}
echo implode('-',$repeat_numbers);
?>
```

**WORKING DEMO:** https://3v4l.org/TvD4S

Comment: Hi,

Yes now it gives the right match numbers but it doesn't show the random numbers anymore. We are almost there :). Can you put back the random numbers? 

Thanks a lot my friend!

Comment: Thanks bro. You are amazing! ;)

Comment: @AmroAwad welcome sir, glad it helps you somehow, Best of luck :)

Comment: Thanks for your help.

Comment: Thanks buddy. I can review the next step what I need to take. Thanks my friend. Do you work freelance too?

Comment: Do you have skype?

Comment: Yeah sure, myskype: `sany2k8`